# Three.js Progressbar for loading Model ? WEBGL

Tags: load, progress-bar, three.js, webgl

know anyomne a possibility to show a progressbar between big models are loading into the webgl renderer canvas ?

Comment: This example webgl_loader_scene.html has a progress bar.

Comment: Thx , but is not commented. So its difficult to filter it whats exactly needed.The Divs (htmlcode) of the progressbar and what jscript part ?

Answer (score 0):

Create you loader and show/hide while progress:

```
THREE.DefaultLoadingManager.onProgress = function (itemPath, itemIndex, totalItems) {
    console.log(itemPath, itemIndex, totalItems);
};
```